# Parentheses and associative operations

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $S$ is a set closed under an associative operation, prove that no matter how you bracket $a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot a_3 \cdots a_n$, retaining the order of the elements, you get the same element in $S$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to familiarise yourself with the [faq] to learn some of the common practices here. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should help you learn how to typeset mathematics. Also, as this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) to help you ask effective homework-related questions.

Comment: I hope that you don't mind that I changed the title to more accurately reflect the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try proving it by induction on n (i.e. on the number of elements operated on).

Comment: Yes ,Induction will definitely do...but may anyone please frame proposition on which induction is to be applied?